# Format a Json string from server side in jquery client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

this the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zzk3rgrm/3/

I am getting the json string from server like this below

JS

```js
var myjsonstring = [{"Key":"item1","Value":"problem statement 1"},{"Key":"item1","Value":"problem statement 2 bigstatement  bigstatement bigstatement bigstatement bigstatement"},{"Key":"item2","Value":"problem statement 1"},{"Key":"item3","Value":"problem statement 1"}];

myjsonstring = JSON.stringify(myjsonstring);
   

alert(myjsonstring);
```

now as you see in code `Key`  , `Value`these words are coming these should be removed . 
"," as seperator coming so should be removed and in place of comma , a new line should be there so that each item shows up in seperate line .

also all the {} [] these characters removed .

so that in the alert it comes like below

```
item1 - problem statement 1
item1- problem statement 2 bigstatement  bigstatement bigstatement bigstatement bigstatement
item2- problem statement 1
item3 -problem statement 1
```

Please help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myjsonstring is an array and can be used as it is without using `stringify`

```js
var myjsonstring = [{"Key":"item1","Value":"problem statement 1"},{"Key":"item1","Value":"problem statement 2 bigstatement  bigstatement bigstatement bigstatement bigstatement"},{"Key":"item2","Value":"problem statement 1"},{"Key":"item3","Value":"problem statement 1"}];
   
var newJson = "";
myjsonstring.forEach(function(ob){
   newJson += ob.Key + ' - ' + ob.Value + '\n';
});
   
alert(newJson);
```

Comment: only problem i am having its not coming in new line as i am showing it in a pop up and not in an alert.trying to make it work in pop up

Answer (score 0):

You could replace your code by this

```
var result = '';
myjsonstring.forEach(function(obj) {
    result = result + obj.Key + " - " + obj.Value + "\n";
});
```